# Реализация quicksort в haskell. Избыточна или нет?

Tags: haskell, теория

В обучающих материалах нашел такую, классическую, реализацию быстрой сортировки

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

И возник у меня вопрос.
Вот в этом куске

```
smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

Выполняется и `smallerSorted` и `biggerSorted`. Т.е., фактически, мы, для разделения на списки *меньших* и *больших* значений пробегаемся по `xs` два раза, тогда как, по хорошему, достаточно одного прохода.

Я прав, или оно тут как-то оптимизируется дополнительно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да список обходится дважды.

Можно соптимизировать

```
import Data.List(partition)

quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let (small, big) = partition ( <= x ) xs
        smallerSorted = quicksort small  
        biggerSorted = quicksort big  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```